# Dynamic throwing Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException on private types

Tags: c#, dynamic, private

I need to write some code to clone a HashSet of any type but the type is not known beforehand. Due to the lack of a non generic interface (unlike dictionary there is no ISet interface just a ISet<>) I have to use reflection. I decided to let dynamic handle the reflection work for me but now iam running into a seemingly very weird problem when I run the following code (heavily simplified from the real world code):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HashSet<ReferenceType> source = new HashSet<ReferenceType>();
        ExtMethodsCloning.DeepClone(source);
    }

    private class ReferenceType { }
}

public static class ExtMethodsCloning
{
    public static void SomeCloningMethodThatHappensToCallClear(dynamic baseObj)
    {
        baseObj.Clear();
    }
}
```

If you move DeepClone to the program class or make ReferenceType public it works. It somehow needs to see ReferenceType in order to work. Even though we are only interested in calling the Clear method which isnt even defined on ReferenceType but on HashSet<>.

How can I workaround this while not having to resort to manually doing the reflection work? Remember the type is not know at compile time so no generics.

EDIT: iam aware of the fact that at some point I would have to create new instances and thus have to call private constructors. If its even possible to call a constructor using dynamic I would expect an error in that case (and workaround it by using reflection) but not now when just calling Clear on the HashSet.

Comment: Is `DeepClone` a `shallow copy` or `deep copy`?

Comment: Doesnt really matter for this example but yes its a deep copy. This will pose a problem in real code though. Still in this case iam not trying to call any constructors yet the error still occurs.

Comment: It does matter, because it is a different to deep copy every item in the HashSet instead of only creating a new Hashset with all the (same) items...

Comment: @CSharper But the OP isn't asking how to make a deep or shallow copy, they're just asking how to clear a hash set.  What they then go on to do with that cleared hash set is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Iam not creating any items in the example code. I removed everything not needed to get this error and it turns it just calling Clear on the hashset will make it throw an error. No constructors are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the need for dynamic here. I'm pretty sure you can do what you need with generics.

EDIT: How to call a generic method by reflection:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var hs1 = new HashSet<SomePrivateClass>();
     CallClear(hs1);
 }

 public static void CallClear(object objectThatIsAHashSet)
 {
     var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Clear", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
     var hsGenericType = objectThatIsAHashSet.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
     var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(hsGenericType);
     genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] {objectThatIsAHashSet});
 }

private class SomePrivateClass { }

public static void Clear<T>(HashSet<T> hs)
{
    hs.Clear();
}
```

EDIT 2: Why doesn't it work with dynamic.

Basically, dynamic only allows access to public members of a type. As such, it cannot be used to call either a private member, or a private type. The basic rule is that if you could not refer to a method in a piece of code using it's type, you cannot access it using dynamic (i.e. you can't use dynamic to break encapsulation).

Comment: Generics require that the type is known at compile time. In my (real) world case this is not the case so no generics. Thats why I explicitly stated that I do not know the type at compile time.

Comment: Edited - shows calling a generic method by reflection.

Comment: But that doesnt explain why dynamic fails me here or how to solve this using dynamic. I know this is possible with reflection and I know dynamic object uses reflection internally but why doesnt it work here?

Comment: Okay. I've explained that too.

Comment: Kinda get it now. If you cannot write it out (replacing dynamic with HashSet<ReferenceType>) for a particular type dynamic wont solve it either. Guess Ill have to resort to other means here.